# Error when releasing from VSTS to Azure Web App

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have created a simple release definition in VSTS that takes a built .net core web app and pushes the build out to an Azure Web App. Unfortunately this fails on the last step with the error:

```
##[error]Error: Offset is out of bounds
```

Does anyone know what might cause this?

Comment: Share the detail release log on the OneDrive. If there isn't the detail error message, you can do it in build and change system.debug to true, then build.

Comment: I can't see system.debug as an option in my release definition, can you tell me where it is?

Comment: It is existing in build definition, create a new build definition with the corresponding steps as release.

Comment: Are there detail errors? Share the detail log on the OneDrive.

Comment: Setting the detailed log helped me fix this issue thanks, I've added details of the fix below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a couple of issues:

1) I was using the .net core build task which required I supply a path to the .csproj, it couldn't find my .csproj. I switched it to the command line task instead and this then fixed that issue.

2) The other issue was that I was using the wrong hosted build agent. When I switched to the VS2017 build agent it all worked.