# Zip file error when releasing from VSTS to Azure Web App

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have created release definition in VSTS that takes a built .net core 3.0 web apps and push the builds out to an Azure Web App. It worked for more than 6 months but recently fails on the deploy step.

```
Possibly unsupported ZIP platform type, 62
##[error]Error: Offset is out of bounds
```

Also I read this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43770194/error-when-releasing-from-vsts-to-azure-web-app). I checked the zip files in working directory and can decompress them.

Comment: Tested the Zip Deploy to Azure Web App, but I couldn't reproduce this issue. Could you share the `Build step definition` and `Deploy Step definition`? You could also set the variable `system.debug = true` and run the pipeline again. Then you could get the detailed debug log.

Answer (score 0):

I found it!
The Malware detection tool remove the published files.